# Changing the number format of a column in Kotlin Dataframe

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dataframe

I'm totally new to Kotlin Dataframes and the documentation seems patchy. I have a dataframe containing a count of items and a calculated percentage of total:

```
countsDF.groupBy("type").count().add("percentage") {
  "count"<Double>() / totalVerifications }.sortBy {it["count"].desc()
}
```

| type | count | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Type1 | 187026 | 0.966103 |
| Type2 | 4546 | 0.023483 |
| Type3 | 1596 | 0.008244 |
| Type4 | 223 | 0.001152 |
| Type5 | 142 | 0.000734 |
| Type6 | 54 | 0.000279 |
| Type7 | 1 | 0.000005 |

**Question: Is there a way to format the `percentage` column to show two decimal places and a percentage sign?**

I can achieve this result by adding a new column like this, but this results in a String type column. It feels like there should be a way to retain the Double type but specify the number format instead.

```
countsDF.groupBy("type").count().add("percentage") {
  DecimalFormat("0.0%").format("count"<Double>() / totalVerifications) }.sortBy {it["count"].desc()
}
```

| type | count | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Type1 | 187026 | 96.6% |
| Type2 | 4546 | 2.3% |
| Type3 | 1596 | 0.8% |
| Type4 | 223 | 0.1% |
| Type5 | 142 | 0.1% |
| Type6 | 54 | 0.0% |
| Type7 | 1 | 0.0% |

Comment: I have not used DataFrames, but maybe you can use BigDecimal as the data type instead of Double as this has the ability to carry scale information which is used in the default toString representations.  Try this `println(BigDecimal.valueOf(12.34567).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))`

Comment: -1

Where do you want to view your tables? Just in the console, or are you running DataFrame in Kotlin Notebooks, Jupyter (Notebooks/Lab), or Datalore? This influences how tables are displayed and which rendering options you have.